# Were attachment media settings removed from Wordpress?

Tags: attachments

In the past, when selecting a picture in the media library, you could see the "attachment display settings".

[image]

I installed wordpress 5.3.2, I uploaded an image to the media library. I don't see attachment display settings anymore. This is also nowhere to be seen in the image block of wordpress. Was it removed, or is it my installation of wordpress?

[image]

Comment: the setting  you are looking for, exists in image block in WordPress.

Comment: In short, the answer is imho *no*, it is still where it always was.

Comment: @Charles you are wrong, it moved.

Answer (score 0):

I found that the link setting to the media file is not at the same location anymore. There is a link icon just above the picture when a user selects the image block. 
After clicking on it, you have the option to link the picture to the media file or the attachment file. You just have to click on "media file" or "attachment file" or add a new URL.

[image]